Need Some Intuition on a Quotient Ring: $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$
I've been diving into the world of algebraic structures and stumbled across something I'm trying to wrap my head around: the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$. It essentially ties back to polynomial functions constrained to the unit circle $S^1$, given the equation $( x^2 + y^2 = 1)$.
Here's where I'm scratching my head: I understand the algebraic framing — polynomials modulo our circle equation — but when it comes to the deeper geometric or topological intuition, I'm kind of lost. How should we visualize or interpret this ring beyond the basic definition? Is there more to the geometric perspective here that I'm missing, especially when it comes to understanding functions on $S^1$?
I haven't been able to fully grasp what this structure might imply in a broader mathematical or physical context. If anyone can shed some light on this or point me toward resources or discussions that tackle this kind of topic, I'd greatly appreciate it!
Thanks in advance for any insights!

For topological intuition you should consider the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 -1)$.

This ring consists of equivalence classes in which $f \sim g \iff f|{S^1}=g|{S^1}$. I don't have any better idea.

Why do you need integer coefficients? For $S^1$, I would consider it as a real manifold.

I'm going to try to give an answer based on what I found helpful to visualise this geometrically when I first saw this, in the hope that it may prove useful for you too.
I remember being puzzled by the appearance of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the definition of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$: if I want to understand "the unit circle", i.e. solutions to the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, then why should I be concerned with $\mathbb{Z}$ in particular? And these variables $x$ and $y$ - do they represent real numbers, or rationals, or what?
What really helped me (thanks to David Zureick-Brown I think) was understanding that I can think of "solutions of the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in the ring $A$" as the same thing as "ring maps from $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ to $A$", since such a map is uniquely determined by choosing the images of $x$ and $y$ in $A$, subject to the constraint that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in $A$.
So while I don't have an easy picture of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ in mind, I do have a nice picture of the set of all maps $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (it's a nice circle in the real plane) or the set of maps $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ (it's a circle in the rational plane), and so on for $A = \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{F}_p,\ldots$
If you know some scheme theory, then this sits together nicely:

$\mathbb{Z}$ is the right choice because it's the initial object in the category of commutative unital rings
the main geometric object representing the circle is the scheme $X=\text{Spec}\left(\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)\right)$, whose point are the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$.
the set of ring maps $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1) \rightarrow A$ are equivalent to the morphisms of schemes $\text{Spec} A \rightarrow \text{Spec}\left(\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)\right)$, the so-called $A$-points of $X$.

